# Compiling simple program doesn't work

Tags: c

I have the following C program (as simple as it gets):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
printf("Test");
}
```

But using the gcc compiler within Cygwin, I cannot get this program to work unless I make the following modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone explain why? What is so special about the "int" and the "return 0;" ?

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: What version of GCC is that? While leaving out `return 0` in `main` is incorrect in C (as opposed to C++), leaving out the return type should make it `int` by default. Your first code compiles successfully (but with warnings) on MinGW GCC 4.5 in `-ansi`, `-std=c90` and `-std=c99` modes.

Comment: @Kos: What do you mean by "(as opposed to C++)"?

Comment: In C++ you can "legally" omit `return 0;` in `main()` IIRC - a standards-aware compiler is then required to make it behave as if there was a `return 0;`. Not that it's important...

Comment: @Kos: And this is also true in C.

Comment: @Charles - hmm... but only in C99, right? My gcc gives a warning in C90 mode, but indeed not in C99.

Comment: @Kos: I'm not 100% sure, I don't have a copy of the obsolete C90 standard to hand. C99 is the current standard after all ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C you are always required to specify your output type. So the `int` is always required (with some compilers, `void` will work too).

The "normal" minimal version is this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on your system you could also have a `char **envp` and `char **apple` there aswell.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_(programming)#C_and_C.2B.2B

Comment: If you say minimal, you don't need the `argc` and `argv` arguments `;)`.

Comment: Also `void` is not an allowed return type in any C or C++ standard.

Comment: @rubenvb: I was talking about the standards, in that case the `argc` and `argv` are required.

Comment: @Kos: True, I have not claimed that it is allowed by any standard. I'm just saying that it works with some compilers ;)

Comment: @WoLpH: Not true. `int main(void)` _must_ be accepted by conforming C (and C++) compilers.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: my bad, you're correct that `int main(void)` is also in the C99 standard.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, much appreciated. So if my program takes in an integer argument, I would need `int main(int index)`, or just `int main(index) { int index; ... }`

Comment: @Amit: in C you _always_ have to specify the type, so the `int` is definately needed.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is the required return type for `main` per the C standard.

Comment: `return 0;` doesn't prevent `main` from returning an unspecified values because "[...] reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0." (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 5.1.2.2.3)

Comment: @Charles, I didn't know that. Updated my answer. Is the same true in C++, btw?

Comment: Yes, in C++ "If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`" (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] / 5)

Answer (score 0):

The int is a return code.  I believe C defaults to returning 0.  Generally speaking a return of 0 means successful completion of program while 1,2,3... would be error codes.  It is often used by programs that want to test if the program ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`int`is the return type for the function, in this case the `main()`. As you know, you always need to specify the return type of a function in C (it could be `void`; there you don't need to return anything)!

When your function has a return type (`int`, for example), you are obligated to put a return sentence (`return 0;`, for example). In C, is a "standard" to return 0 when a function executed correctly. Also, when you run your program, you can obtain the value returned after the execution (in this case it will be 0). If the execution of your program would terminate erroneously, then you could return any other value (-1, 1, 2, etc.) and it is easier for you to detect the error and debug it.